# Can GNU makefiles rules have processes as requirements, if so how?

Tags: makefile, process

At some step of my software building automatization, which I attempt to implement using GNU make Makefiles, I run into the case of not only having targets a requirement being source files, but as a sort of different type of requirement I would like the target to depend on another software is started and hence exist as an operation system process.

Such a program could be background process but also a foreground process such as a Webbrowser which running a HTML5 application, which might play a role in a building process by for instance interacting with files it is fed through the building process.

I would hence like to write a rule somewhat like this:

```
.PHONY: firefoxprocess

Html5DataResultFile: HTML5DataSourceFile firefoxprocess
     cp HTML5DataSourceFile folder/checked/by/html5app/
     waitforHtml5DataResultFile

firefoxprocess:
     /usr/bin/firefox file://url/to/html5app &
```

As seen I have taken the idea that .PHONY targets are somewhat non-file targets and hence would allow for requirering a process to be started?
Yet I a unsure if that is right. The documentation of GNU make is excellent and quite large and I am unsure understood it completely. To the best of my knowledge the documentation did not really report on the use of processes being used in rules, which motivates the question here.

My feeling has been that pidfiles are somewhat a link between processes and files, but they come with several problems (i.e. race conditions, uniqueness etc)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a Makefile dependency tree includes elements that aren't naturally or necessarily time-dependent files.  There are two answers:

1. create a file to represent the step, or
2. just do the work "in line" as part of the step.

The second option is usually easiest.  For instance, if a target file is to be created in a directory that might not exist yet, you don't want to make the directory name itself a dependency, because that would cause the file to be out of date whenever the directory changed.  Instead, I do:

```
d/foo: 
    @test -d d || mkdir -p d
    ...
```

In your case, you could something similar; you just need a way to test for a running instance of firefox, and to be able to start it.  Something like this might do:

```
Html5DataResultFile: HTML5DataSourceFile
    pgrep firefox || { /usr/bin/firefox && sleep 5; }
    cp HTML5DataSourceFile folder/checked/by/html5app/
    waitforHtml5DataResultFile
```

The `sleep` call just lets FF initialize, because it might not be ready to do anything the instant it returns.

The problem with option #1 in your case is that it's undependable and a little circular.  Firefox won't reliably remove the pidfile if the process dies.  If it *does* successfully remove the file when it exits, and re-creates it when it restarts, you have a new problem: the timestamp on the file spuriously defines any dependencies as out of date, when in fact the restarted process hasn't invalidated them.